# For new objects in R, how to assign values through subscripting?

Tags: r, oop, subset, variable-assignment, subscript

For new objects in R, how can I specify assignments to subscripted elements? As in `object[3] <- new value`. Here is a specific example of the problem I have.

```
# Rectangle example:
Rectangle <- function(a, b,...){
   R <- list(a=a, b=b, others=list(...))
   structure(R, class="Rectangle")
}#
`[.Rectangle` <- function(R,ind){
   if(ind==1) return(R$a)
   if(ind==2) return(R$b)
   if(ind>=3) return(R$others[[ind-2]])   
}#
R <- Rectangle(2,3,"other1","other2")
> R[1]; R[2]; R[3]; R[4]; 
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] "other1"
[1] "other2"
> R[4] <- "new.other"; 
> R[1]; R[2]; R[3]; R[4];
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] "other1"
[1] "other2"
```

Clearly, the assignment to the subscripted object hasn't worked. I would like to know the syntax to define such assignments properly. That is, I would need an example for the following:

```
`[<-.Rectangle` <- function(){  }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To override subset-assign, your function needs to accept three arguments (`x, index, value`) and return the modified object. It is important that the third parameter is called *exactly* `value`, since R internally calls the function using that name (rather than positionally).

Here’s an example:

```
`[<-.Rectangle` = function (x, index, value) {
    if (index == 1L) {
        x$a = value
    }
    else if (index == 2L) {
        x$b = value
    }
    else {
        x$others[[index - 2L]] = value
    }
    x
}
```

It probably goes without saying that this is a pretty convoluted logic, I’m not convinced that real-world code should have objects with such an API.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was after. And I agree with you that my example is very artificial, indeed. I had to include the list to make the assignment fails, as otherwise, it correctly assigned for indices 1 and 2. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

```
> str(R)
List of 3
 $ a     : num 2
 $ b     : num 3
 $ others:List of 2
  ..$ : chr "other1"
  ..$ : chr "other2"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "Rectangle"

> R[4]='hello'
> str(R)
List of 4
 $ a     : num 2
 $ b     : num 3
 $ others:List of 2
  ..$ : chr "other1"
  ..$ : chr "other2"
 $       : chr "hello"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "Rectangle"


> R[4]
[1] "other2"

> R[[4]]
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, although this is not quite what I was looking for. I was rather trying to get at the syntax for `[<-.`, in general; rather than solving this particular assignment problem. Thank you, though.